# Set insert doing a weird number of comparisons

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I am unable to explain the number of comparisons that std::set does while inserting a new element. Here is an example:

For this code

```
struct A {
    int i = 0;
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        ++i;
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    A a;

    set<int, A> s1(a);

    s1.insert(1);    
    cout << s1.key_comp().i << endl;

    s1.insert(2);    
    cout << s1.key_comp().i << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
0
3
```

Why does inserting a second element require 3 comparisons? o_O

Comment: Looks odd on first glance. Which C++ standard are you using? Which stl?

Comment: Is it consistent between debug and non-debug builds?

Comment: I augmented the test case to some more comparisons [on ideone](http://ideone.com/xSa524), it yields `[0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Comment: @Angew yes it is unfortunately. The same result for both debug and release

Comment: @ Bathsheba I am using C++ 11 and here are details of my compiler:
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 4):

This is a side effect of using a red-black tree to implement `std::set`, which requires more comparisons initially compared to a standard binary tree.

Comment: Could you expand on why a red-black tree would require more comparisons up-front. I am not familiar enough with this structure to understand why it's a requirement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The two extra comparisons stem from the fact that red-black tree nodes always have two leaves, so the first insertion technically adds the root and two (null) leaves, when the second element is added it has to be compared with both leaves because whichever leaf is compared with first will of course come back as null. At least that's my educated guess because I'm not overly familiar myself :p.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the particular as they will depend on your `std::set` implementation, however determining the equality of two items requires two comparisons, as it is based on the fact that `not (x < y) and not (y < x)` implies `x == y`.

Depending on how the tree is optimized, you might thus be paying a first comparison to determine whether it should go left or right, and then two comparisons to check whether it's equal or not.

The Standard has no requirement except that the number of comparisons be O(log N) where N is the number of items already in the `set`. Constant factors are a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: I also was expecting two comparisons for the non equality test, but one of those tests implies also the result on whether the element should go on right or on left, so I don't get your point about the third comparison

Comment: @IssamT.: That is because you assume that the result of the check for left/right is re-used for the equality test. It is not necessarily so, as my second paragraph indicates.

Comment: @ Matthieu M: I got your point. But I usually assume that stl libraries are implemented in a quite smart way, so it would be weird if the implementation doesn't re-use the result of the previously done comparison

Comment: @IssamT.: It's a rather premature optimization. When a tree has N levels, you have up to N comparisons to locate the place, and then 2 for the equality. The difference between N+1 (optimized) and N+2 (non-optimized) is not exactly tremendous.

Comment: When I think about it, it does make sense: remembering the result of the last comparison would add an overhead to each operation. With a big tree these can probably outweigh the single extra comparison that you are seeing. On top of that, you'd get cyclometric complexity increase.